# Automating repeated editing operations in Intellij

Tags: java, refactoring, intellij-idea

What are the ways in Intellij IDEA to automate repeated editing operations?

For example I have a file with few dozens of entries like the following:

```
public static final Test1 = new Test(A a1, B b);
public static final Test2 = new Test(A a2, B b);
public static final Test3 = new Test(A a3, B b);
public static final Test4 = new Test(A a4, B b);
```

I would like to replace all `B b` in a file, and pass a `null` parameter instead. It is easy to do in editors like `gvim` where normally you would record a `macro` and repeat it. What are the usual ways to do such automation where refactoring capabilities of Intellij are limited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can identify a pattern you can always copy the text over to textpad or something similar and do a regex replace then copy the text back. I do it very often.

For your particular example, try this in textpad -

1. F8 - for replace dialog
2. Find What: (Test([^,])+([^)]+)
3. Replace with: \1, null
4. Check Regular Expression checkbox

Comment: I agree that my example is too simple to illustrate an issue, but there are often cases where simple regex replace will not work. Say what if I wanted to refactor out the argument from a constructor, move it to a different file and pass it to a different class' construction. There are many more instances where more sophisticated processing is required. Macros seems to be helpful in a way, but they often don't work as you would expect them to in Intellij.

And yes, regular expressions is definitely a helpful way to do more stuff than plain find-replace!!

Comment: Ya true, that sort of refactoring isnt available. You can however change method signatures/Constructor arguments etc, but you cannot keep the same signature and say change argumant values for certain calls - This isnt refactoring - technically so to speak.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can use the keyboard macro recorder:

[image]

Or you could use IDEA's [structural search and replace](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/structural-search-and-replace.html) feature

Answer (score 3):

It is easy in IntelliJ IDEA too. You can switch to column mode editing (Edit | Column Mode from the main menu), then select the columns you want to replace and just type your `null`'s

Also check this screencast: http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/column-mode-editing-with-intellij-idea